# Add a link near error message

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to add a link after an error message appears. Currently, I have this in my code:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CV2" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="Validate" 
     ForeColor="Red" OnServerValidate="Server_Validate" ValidationGroup="group" 
     ErrorMessage="You have not validated." Display="Dynamic" Enabled="false" 
     ControlToValidate="txtAmount" />
```

the javascript:

```
function Validate(source, arguments) {
            var validAmount = document.getElementById('<%= validate.ClientID %>').innerHTML.replace('$', '').replace(/,/g, '');
            if (arguments.Value > validAmount)
                arguments.IsValid = false;
            else
                arguments.IsValid = true;
}
```

C# code:

```
protected void Server_Validate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
  try
  {
     //Some C# code here.
  }
}
```

What's the best approach to this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
CV2.ErrorMessage = "<a href='www.google.com'>You have not validated.</a>";
```

I didn't test it, but I know I can add markup to my Label text.